Error: target/idl/sol_404.json doesn't exist. Did you run `anchor build`?
I run anchor build , and it indeeded generate a sol404.json , but when I run the anchor test it shows /Users/brooke/Desktop/sol404/node_modules/.bin/ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 'tests/**/*.ts'  Error: target/idl/sol_404.json doesn't exist. Did you runanchor build?
here is my test code
const jellyTokenMintMetadataPDA = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .pdas()
    .metadata({ mint: JellyTokenMintPDA });

    const usdcTokenMintMetadataPDA = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .pdas()
    .metadata({ mint: UsdcTokenMintPDA });

    const nftTokenMintMetadataPDA = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .pdas()
    .metadata({ mint: NftTokenMintPDA });

    const tx = await program.methods
    .createmint(jellymetadata.uri, usdcmetadata.uri, nftmetadata.uri, jellymetadata.name, usdcmetadata.name, nftmetadata.name, jellymetadata.symbol, usdcmetadata.symbol, nftmetadata.symbol)
    .accounts({
      admin: admin.publicKey,
      jellyTokenMint: JellyTokenMintPDA,
      usdcTokenMint: UsdcTokenMintPDA,
      nftMint: NftTokenMintPDA,
      jellyTokenAccount: JellyTokenAccount,
      usdcTokenAccount: UsdcTokenAccount,
      nftTokenAccount: NftTokenAccount,
      jellyMetadataAccount: jellyTokenMintMetadataPDA,
      usdcMetadataAccount: usdcTokenMintMetadataPDA,
      nftMetadataAccount: nftTokenMintMetadataPDA,
      tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
    })
    .rpc();
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);

here is my anchor.toml
[toolchain]

[features]
seeds = false
skip-lint = false

[programs.localnet]
sol404 = "EzkLoHgcsJ3XCxsTq2a7kmkwAcYh1CGoJtjghCVGescK"

[registry]
url = "https://api.apr.dev"


[provider]
cluster = "Localnet"
wallet = "/Users/b/.config/brooke/solana/id.json"

[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"


here is my Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "sol404"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "sol404"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = {version = "0.29.0", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = {version = "0.29.0", features = ["metadata"]}
solana-program = "1.18.11"

any one can help me?

I assume there will be a discrepancy in naming of your project. You can see the idl is generated to sol404.json and is searched at file sol_404.json by anchor test.
The code of anchor workspace loading is here
https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/v0.30.0/ts/packages/anchor/src/workspace.ts#L64
The idl path is generated from programName.
You define that program.localnet is with sol404. The programs/sol404/Cargo.toml may use the name sol-404 in name within [lib](?).
I would suggest to change the [programs.localnet] of Anchor.toml file from sol404 to sol_404.
Or to unite the naming in some way within the Cargo.toml and Anchor.toml files.

In the programs/sol404/Cargo.toml , I use the name sol404instead of sol_404, I dunno why the name runanchor test different with the name I use in Cargo.toml & Anchor.toml

Yeap, I'm not sure why this naming mix happens in Anchor neither.
